# Basic server with email service

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, web, server

I would like to ask for some guidance, i want to host one of my project website.
I've done the front end side and put in a folder name `Client`.
It contains assets required in multiple folders, `index.html` and some more pages with text/photos but there is another page named  `registration.html` where people who like to sign up the project could register.
Sign up page looks like this

```html
<form method="post" action="formdata">
  <input type="text" id="name" value="" placeholder="name"/>
  ...<!-- other fields -->
</form>
```

Fields from above should be sent to my email.

Now here is where I'm stuck, server side.
In a folder named `server` i wrote this simple code `server.js` to host the pages but without any functionality.

```js
var app = require('koa')();
var serve = require('koa-static');

app.use(serve('../Client'));

app.listen(8080);
```

How could I make this server get data from the client and send it to my email?

Comment: project front end is in which technology ? angular js or ?

Comment: No, just plain html with just a bit of javascript. Its a presentation website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make AJAX Requests to send data across from the frontEnd to backEnd.

If you are using plain vanilla JS, you could do this like

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("POST", "/sendEmail", true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhttp.send("fname=Henry&lname=Ford");
```

Or If you are using jQuery, you could directly use the [post](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) method

Over your backend, You will need to setup a route to listen to this request, Since you are using Koa

```
var koa = require('koa');
var http = require('http');
var router = require('koa-router')();
var bodyParser = require('koa-body')();

router.post('/sendEmail', bodyParser, function *(next){
  console.log(this.request.body);
  yield(next);
});
```

Now, You can use mailto attribute on your forms to open the mail client from the front-end itself without the need of making a request, Something like this would popup the mail client with a body

```
<a href="mailto:someone@example.com?subject=Suggestions&body=Your%20suggestions%20are%20really%20important%20to%20us%20,thanks!">Send suggestions!</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Shivam thanks, worked as expeced.
Data send from client is encoded with JSON.stringify(); and send as a string

```js
var app = require('koa')();
var http = require('http');
var router = require('koa-router')();
var bodyParser = require('koa-body')();
var serve = require('koa-static');

app.use(serve('../Client')); //serve public files

router.post("/sendEmail", bodyParser, function *(next){
    //get form data from client
    console.log("Got data")
    var datastring = this.request.body;
    console.log(datastring);
    yield(next);
});

app.use(router.routes()); //use routes

app.use(function *(){
    //redirect 404
    this.redirect('/index.html');
});

console.log("Running on 8080");
app.listen(8080);
```

Here is the code, maybe someone else is gonna need this too